# Where is the RHEL7 kernel source code installed?

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, linux-kernel, rpm

I install the `Linux` kernel source code RPM:

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -ivh kernel-3.10.0-229.el7.src.rpm
warning: kernel-3.10.0-229.el7.src.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
Updating / installing...
   1:kernel-3.10.0-229.el7            ################################# [100%]
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
```

The installation process seems success, but using `rpm -ql kernel-3.10.0-229.el7.src` command can't find where the source code is installed:

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -ql kernel-3.10.0-229.el7.src
package kernel-3.10.0-229.el7.src is not installed
```

Where is the `RHEL7` kernel source code installed?

Update: `rpm -qa | grep kernel` command ouput:

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa | grep kernel
kernel-headers-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
kernel-devel-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.1.11-19.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: Add output of "rpm -qa|grep kernel", just to show what is actually installed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source packages are not added to the rpm database, so they will not show on query.

Probable location is ~/rpmbuild/{SOURCES,SPECS} with SOURCES containing the package sources and distribution patches while the SPECS subdirectory containing the .spec file being used to build the package (see rpmbuild (8) man page for details).

If you can't find the sources there, than reinstall with the -vv option to check the location if it's overwritten:

```
$ rpm -ivvh kernel-3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.src.rpm 
--- snip ---
Updating / installing...
   1:kernel-3.10.0-229.7.2.el7        ################################# [100%]
D: ========== Directories not explicitly included in package:
D:          0 /home/user/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
D:          1 /home/user/rpmbuild/SPECS/
D: ==========
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks! BTW, why there are so many warnings when installing kernel*.*.src.rpm?

Comment: There's actually only one warning that is repeated for every file that is created. The rpm says that the files must belong to user "builder" (the account used by redhat for developing). Since this user does not exists in the current system the files will be created as the default user "root" or if you run the command as normal user, the user running the command and display a warning.

Answer (score 0):

It should be under **/usr/src/kernel**.

if you dont find it, you can try

**rpm -qa| grep -w kernel-devel**

**rpm -ql kernel-devel-x.x.x.x.x**

This will give you the location of files installed by kernel rpm.

Bye the way, kernel source should be installed with kernel-devel package, rather kernel-x.x.x.x

Comment: What is the difference between `kernel` and `kernel-devel`?

Comment: try rpm -ql kernel-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64

Comment: kernel-devel is actually not full source code, but contains enough to compile modules.